# NSArray extract items

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I extract data from a NSMutableArray using NSPredicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", value];
NSArray *results = [array_to_search filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

When I use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

I get:

```
({pub_id = 102 "pub_name" = "some publisher" city = "Peshawar"});
```

I would like to extract values of all 3 items `pub_id`, `pub_name`, `city`.

Comment: xcode is just an IDE and irrelevant for this question.

Answer (score 1):

What's being returned is an array containing 1 object (which denoted by the curly braces `{}` means a dictionary). To extract each of the three components, you can do:

```
NSString *pub_id = [[results objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"pub_id"];
NSString *pub_name = [[results objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"pub_name"];
NSString *city = [[results objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"city"];
```

Bear in mind that this solution is only suitable for the example you've provided. If the query ever returns more than 1 object in the array, you'll need to use enumeration/for loop to read the results.

Comment: the dot notation shows a error instead asks for ->, in any case that to does not work since city, pub_id, pub_name show error

Comment: What do you mean they show an error? Edit your original question to include what exactly you're storing in array_to_search, and show how the object is structured. This will help us understand your question further.

Comment: the error message i get "No member named 'city' in 'struct_objc_object'"

Comment: i have not used any extraordinary method to create the array (NSMutableArray), the returned results are similar to what can be seen on this page https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html  , the array display data correctly in a NSTableview.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I assumed the object returned was defined by you, when in actual fact the single object is simply an NSDictionary. I forgot that elements inside curly braces `{ }` mean dictionary (and similarly elements inside round brackets `( )` mean array). I've adjusted my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood that you want to get those three objects separately, isn't it?
In case I am right:

```
NSLog(@"PUBID: %d \n PUBNAME: %@ \n CITY: %@", [[results objectAtIndex:0] intValue], [results objectAtIndex:1], [results objectAtIndex:2]);
```

This code should print
       PUBID: 102 
         PUBNAME: some publisher
       CITY: Peshawar.

So your result from

> [array_to_search filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

is another array and you can use that with objectAtIndex:

Comment: i did try NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [results valueForKey:@"pub_name"]] and it returned (\n  Some publisher\n)

Comment: Have you tried it? I cant give it a try but I am almost completely sure this should work.

Comment: I didn't see your last comment. So what you are saying is that results is a 'mix' of an NSArray and NSDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the values from a dictionary into an array do:

```
[dictionary allValues];
```

Comment: getting another array would take me back to square one     NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [results valueForKey:@"pub_name"]] and it returned (\n Some publisher\n)

Answer (score 0):

The object you get out of the array using the prodicate is apparently an NSDictionary. Use the following code:

```
NSString *city = [[results objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"city"];
```

et cetera.